# Javascript Firebug error

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I have a JavaScript code **coupon.js** defined as follows -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.appnitro').submit( function() {
$.ajax({
 url : $(this).attr('action'),
 type : $(this).attr('method'),
 dataType: 'json',
 data : $(this).serialize(),
 success : function( data ) {
 for(var id in data) {
 jQuery('#' + id).html( data[id] );
 }
 }
 });
```

Now Firebug throws following error -

```
jQuery is not defined
[Break on this error] jQuery(document).ready(function(){\n
```

Can someone explain the error and ways to remove it?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this into the `head` section of your page before any other script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be in the <head>. Many JS Guru's are advocating putting these at the end of the Body to speed up the page load.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your page doesn't include jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you referencing your JQuery JS script files? Either they're pointing to a location that doesn't exist, they don't exist, or you used a self-closing script tag ()